# How to look at code in WordPress repositories without downloading?

Tags: search, git, svn

A lot of questions are about plugins and themes, that you don't necessarily have installed. Downloading zip archive, unpacking and opening in editor seems like a too much hassle.

If only there was a way to just browse source of WordPress and all of plugins and themes in its repository...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good news and more good news!

First - all of the code related to WordPress itself and its repositories resides in version control system ([Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)). Among other things that makes publicly available sites with all code in plain sight:

- http://core.svn.wordpress.org/
- http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/
- http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/

One not so obvious result of that - if you can see it, so can our overlord Google. Basically you can google through that code quite successfully by adding modifier like `site:http://core.svn.wordpress.org/` to your query.

But that is not all. WordPress project also uses [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). That is actually piece of software, not just mythical place for WP demigods to hang out.

Among other things trac has *browser* feature that interfaces with SVN and provides prettified, ajaxified and in other ways glorious human-friendly way to browse through code:

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser
- http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser
- http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser

Note that it can take a long time to open root of browser for plugins and themes, because there are tons of either. It is usually faster to type in name of specific plugin/theme at end of URL (it will be same as in repository), for example http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/hybrid

Also note that trac browser gives nice way to link to specific lines of code for reference, with number of line for an anchor http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/hybrid/0.8/index.php#L13

In addition to wordpress.org theme repository, free themes for wordpress.com are available as public SVN repository at:

- https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/

While development of WordPress is happening via SVN so far, GitHub mirror was created (first maintained by Mark Jaquith and later promoted to official status):

- https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress